# Passing array in many to many relationship to the controller- laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship between Category and posts tables like this:

Category class:

```
class Category extends Model {
public function posts()
    {
    //return $this->hasMany('App\Posts','category_id');
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Posts', 'categories_post', 'category_id', 'post_id')
    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Posts class:

```
class Posts extends Model {
   public function category()
   {
    //return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id');
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'categories_post', 'post_id', 'category_id')
    ->withTimestamps();
   }
}
```

When I need to access only one category's posts I do this in my controller:

```
    public function cat($category_id)
{
$posts= $category_id->posts()->paginate(7);
return view('cat')->with('posts',$posts);
}
```

**Edit**

to make this work, I added this in "RouteServiceProvider.php" file:

```
    public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);
    $router->model('categories','App\Category');
}
```

and this works perfectly. The problem is, **I have another controller which should get the posts for multiple categories** :

```
    public function index()
{
    $title = 'news';
    $categories= [1, 2, 10, 11];
    // Here is the problem:
    $posts= $categories->posts()->paginate(7);
    return view('news')->with('posts',$posts)->with('title',$title);
}
```

This gives me this error: *Call to a member function posts() on a non-object*

I know there is something wrong with calling the array, but I don't know how to solve it. Can any one help me please :)

---

### **The solution**

after what *Thomas Van der Veen* said in his answer , I came up with this controller which is working perfectly:

```
    public function index()
{
    $title = 'news';
    $category_ids = [1, 2, 10, 11];
    $posts = Posts::whereHas('category', function($query) use ($category_ids) {
$query->whereIn('id', $category_ids);
    })->get();
    return view('news')->with('posts',$posts)->with('title',$title);
}
```

Comment: $categories is simply just an array of numbers? It's not linked at all to your categories model

Comment: Not even sure how you can call $categorie_id->posts() on an id? Is it an intger? Should be an object though

Comment: `$posts= \App\Category::find($category_id)->posts()->paginate(7);`

Comment: I edited my question to show you how I made `$categorie_id->posts()` work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$category_ids = [1, 2, 10, 11];

$posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category_ids) {

    $query->whereIn('id', $category_ids);

});
```

See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

Comment: Thank you very much this really helped me. I'll update my question to add the final controller